# docker compose up pass in the variable at startup. Then how to unset this variable in the container

Tags: docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/home/wwwroot/
            - ./config/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        environment:
            - FLAG
        command: /bin/sh -c "ls && echo $$FLAG >/flag;echo export FLAG="" >> /root/.bashrc  && tail -f /dev/null"
        networks:
            - code-network
    php:
        image: php:7.0-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./app:/home/wwwroot/
        networks:
            - code-network

networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

.env

```
FLAG=flag{6f1160f8-c147-4e07-9b5e-a6149e34ba34}
```

`echo export FLAG="" >> /root/.bashrc` only work in bash, but not other shells.

If you use `sh` to enter the container, the `FLAG` environment variable is still displayed. How to fix it